# How to update button text on Tkinter python (button1 not defined error message)

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to update the button text on a TKinter GUI (learning TKinter!) but am coming up against a small problem. I am getting a button1 is not defined. I am sure I am missing something stupid!

```
def toggleText():  
 if button1["text"] == "hi":
 button1["text"] = "bye"
else:
 button1["text"] = "hi"

def selection():
 button1 = Button(tab1, text="hi", command=toggleText, height=5, width=10)
 button1.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=10, pady=10)
 root.mainloop() 
selection()

HERE IS THE OUTPUT I GET:
if button1["text"] == "hi":
NameError: name 'button1' is not defined
```

Comment: fix your indentation and you should provide a [mre], anways, the problem is that `button1` is a local variable in the `selection` function, so you can't reference it elsewhere, you could for example do `global button1` at the start of `selection` function and if you call it before `toggleText` then you shouldn't have any issues, you can also pass the button as an argument to `toggleText` using an anonymous function and doing it with `config` after defining `button1`

Comment: Are you familiar with the concepts of local and global variables? `button1` is a local variable.

Comment: Thank you both for your help, that makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options, the easiest is to just use `global` to make `button1` a global name which can be accessed anywhere, just make sure that you call `toggleText` after calling `selection`:

```py
def selection():
    global button1
    button1 = Button(...)
    ...
```

The other option is to use function arguments (which is better practice in this case):

```py
# make `toggleText` accept an argument for button:
def toggleText(btn):
    if btn['text'] == 'hi':
        btn['text'] = 'bye'
    ...


def selection():
    # use lambda to pass an argument and since it is a lambda name
    # `button1` can be not yet defined since `lambda` is not called immediately
    button1 = Button(..., command=lambda: toggleText(button1))
    ...
```

Also:
I strongly advise against using wildcard (`*`) when importing something, You should either import what You need, e.g. `from module import Class1, func_1, var_2` and so on or import the whole module: `import module` then You can also use an alias: `import module as md` or sth like that, the point is that don't import everything unless You actually know what You are doing; name clashes are the issue.

I strongly suggest following [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Function and variable names should be in `snake_case`, class names in `CapitalCase`. Have two blank lines around function and class declarations. Object method definitions have one blank line around them.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will take on board your feedback regarding the PEP 8 formatting. Much appreciated!

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to change the button colour on click?
I have followed the guide on Python but nothing changes: 

https://pythonexamples.org/python-tkinter-change-background-color-during-mouse-click/

Comment: @MediterraneanCoder that guide is about how to change color during the pressing of the button (i.e. if you hold the button you will see those colors), really it is the same way as you change text, for example in the `toggleText` function under one of the conditions place `btn['bg'] = 'red'` (or any other color, also possible to use `btn.config(bg='red')`) and under the other condition place `btn['bg'] = 'blue'` (or any other color), then clicking on the button will change colors

Comment: thank you again for your help! That's worked a treat.